# I took out the MissingSplitsManager because it is deprecated and now I'm back to getting missing resources exceptions and other related exceptions

Tags: android

I started using the `MissingSplitsManager` a long time ago because I had a lot of `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException` exceptions. They happen quickly after I release a new version.

All those exceptions that made no sense pretty much went away while using `MissingSplitsManager` but now it has been deprecated and as soon as I removed it, those exceptions came back.

So what can I do to fix this problem? The resources it is complaining about are clearly there, I think users are just installing the wrong split of the bundle on their own.